# Generic T to call overloaded functions

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want to do something like this:

```
public class Object1 {
    public int number{get;set;}
}
public class Object2 {
    public int number{get;set;} 
}

public class Object3 {
    public int number{get;set;} 
}

main();

public void main(){
    var objects1 = new List<Object1>{new Object1{number=1} , new Object1{number=2}};
     test<Object1>(objects1);
}

public List<Object3> test<T>(IEnumerable<T> objs){
    var rv = new List<Object3>();

    foreach (var o in objs)
    {
        var foo = overloaded(o);
        rv.Add(foo);
    }

    return rv;
}  

public Object3 overloaded(Object1 obj){
    // Run very specific things to Object1
    return new Object3{number=obj.number+1}; 
}

public Object3 overloaded(Object2 obj){
    // Run very specific things to Object2
    return new Object3{number=obj.number+2};    
}
```

You can directly run/edit the code here, with error handling:
http://csharppad.com/gist/6ff5f13cac8f0e5735be

The error I get is `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T' to 'Object1'` - So how can I do this? The idea is that Object1 and Object2 have 95% of their code identical, it's that last 5% that I need to have it do something specific for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dynamic` to in your `test` method, just note that there are performance implications:

```
overloaded((dynamic)obj);
```

Comment: I get `Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context`

Comment: That's what I thought you meant, but now I get `The best overloaded method match for 'Submission#0.overloaded(Submission#0.Object1)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Sorry. I got it with `overloaded((dynamic)o);` error message wasn't obvious

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I was able to come up with this

```
public class Object1 {
    public int number{get;set;}
}
public class Object2 {
    public int number{get;set;} 
}

public class Object3 {
    public int number{get;set;} 
}

main();

public void main(){
    var objects1 = new List<Object1>{new Object1{number=1} , new Object1{number=2}};
     test<Object1>(objects1);
}


public List<Object3> test<T>(IEnumerable<T> objs){
    var rv = new List<Object3>();

    foreach (var o in objs)
    {
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(Object1)){
            rv.Add(overloaded((Object1)(object)o));
        } else {
            rv.Add(overloaded((Object2)(object)o));
        }
    }

    return rv;
}


public Object3 overloaded(Object1 obj){
    return new Object3{number=obj.number+1}; 
}

public Object3 overloaded(Object2 obj){
    return new Object3{number=obj.number+2};    
}
```

This works, but seems hacky to me. Wondering what the best way is!

Comment: Your code will be complex and it will pollute with nested IF condition. What are your trying to accomplish here? Why don't you apply some design pattern if you do mind?

Comment: I am trying to take the logic of dealing with enumerating through each objecting and running `overloaded` on them. Instead of making 2-10 `test` functions, there is only one `test`. Overloaded is very specific though, and cannot be generalize (Not demonstrated in the example)

Answer (score 0):

I would reverse your thinking.

Try this:

```
private void test<T>(T obj){
    // Do common stuff

}
public void overloaded(Object1 obj){
    test(obj);
    Console.WriteLine("Do Object 1 stuff");   
}
public void overloaded(Object2 obj){
    test(obj);
    Console.WriteLine("Do Object 2 stuff");   
}
```

and call `overloaded` instead of calling `test`.

Comment: I have to run overloaded on each object, not sure how to that with this pattern

Comment: @ParoX can you pass a projected innumerable with linqs select?

Comment: LINQ is pretty new to me but I am flexible I think, I am interested in what you are proposing

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection

```
interface IObject 
{
   int number {get;set;}
}

public class Object1 : IObject {
    public int number{get;set;}
}
public class Object2 : IObject  {
    public int number{get;set;} 
}

public class Object3 : IObject  {
    public int number{get;set;} 
}

public IObject overloaded(IObject obj){
    // Run very specific things to Object1
    return new IObject {number=obj.number+1}; 
}
```